# Why can't I add a local GitHub repository into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github

There's this project that has been discontinued that I want to have in my Eclipse workspace so that I can maintain it for my own personal use (the author of the project is fine with this). I have the repository from GitHub downloaded and am trying to import it into Eclipse using this tutorial: https://github.com/collab-uniba/socialcde4eclipse/wiki/How-to-import-a-GitHub-project-into-Eclipse.

After defining the directory of the local repository and clicking "Next", I'm presented with this: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyRM6.png)

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded it as Git repository and not the latest version as ZIP? As far as I know, GitHub only offers the latter, and you have to clone the Git repository with, e.g. Eclipse to get the full history.

Comment: I have the ZIP because that's what the developer gave me, as it is a slightly older version. This is because the latest version is a WIP version 2 (incomplete, and will never be completed as it was discontinued).

Comment: Does the ZIP file contain a `.git` folder? If not, it's not a Git repository.

Comment: Nah it doesn't. What's the difference? Is there a way I can get a Git repository "version" of the downloaded code (as a ZIP) I have so that I can edit the project in Eclipse?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All the history is in the `.git` folder. Without that, you only have the current state.

Comment: If I use the URL of the repository, I can view it in Eclipse. From Eclipse, I can see that there is a .git folder. How can I use this to get a previous version?

Comment: If you have the GitHub website URL, just drop it on Eclipse an the clone dialog will open. Or manually, in the _Git Repositories_ view click the clone button and when finish right-click the repository and do _Import Projects..._. _File > Import..._ should work also.

Comment: This is the part I've already done. I'm viewing the repository in Eclipse right now. The problem is, this is the latest version of the project, which is a WIP of a version 2 of the project. I have a downloaded ZIP of the code from a previous version of the project, and this is what I want to be able to edit in Eclipse.

Comment: Is the previous version a branch, a tag or only a commit? In all three cases right-click it and choose _Create Branch..._ and keep the check box _Check out new branch_ checked.

Comment: The previous version (the ZIP I have downloaded) is a commit I believe, as it has a bunch of letters and numbers appended to the end of the file name. How do I get the "Create Branch" option as a right-click option?

Comment: In the _History_ view you can right-click that commit.

Comment: I'm so confused, what? I have the ZIP file in my downloads folder, and I have Eclipse installed on my system. What exactly do I do from this point?

Comment: You have the cloned repository and it is shown in the _Git Repositories_ view, right? Then you can go to the _History_ view right-click the commit and choose _Create Branch..._

Comment: Oh I thought you were talking about the ZIP file I have downloaded... So how do I go to the history view? I can't see it

Comment: _Window > Show View > Other..._. Please show what you have in your _Git_ perspective (_Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other..._).

Comment: Okay that's great, I've created the new branch from the commit in question. How do I now edit this as a project in Eclipse?

EDIT: Never mind I've figured it out, I have to "check out" the branch and then the project becomes what it was like after that commit (if my understanding is correct). Thanks for your help man!